# Chrome - Crashes on extension load

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

I have a google account that, when signed in to chrome, loads an extension that causes chrome to crash.

I can't figure out which one causes the crash, as chrome won't stay up long enough for me to figure it out.

Is there a way to remove which extensions are associated with your google account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try deleting your Google Chrome User Data folder and letting Chrome resync from the Cloud. The Uers Data folder is typically at "C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data". You can safely delete the whole of the User Data folder and then re-open Google Chrome and sign in again. Hopefully this will fix the problem!

Comment: The problem is, when I log in to Chrome, it loads the bad extension, which then causes Chrome crash.

Comment: Have you tried accessing Chrome on another PC?

Comment: Alternatively you could try uninstalling Chrome and re-installing. This will not affect your Chrome settings & apps as they are all stored in the 'cloud' and will be reloaded when you sign into the re-installed Chrome.

Comment: Right, and that could data is what I want to alter.  I've narrowed it down to the Chromecast extension that keeps causing Chrome to crash.

Comment: I am on debian  how to delete local data ?